# NamedQuery (JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0)

Tags: jpa

Anyone know what is the difference for NamedQuery in JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0 ?

I have done some research and realize that createNamedQuery sometimes have one or two parameter? 
Is it because of JPA version or Hibernate?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Errm, read the javadocs? That should the start point of any "research" with a standardised API. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 2):

JPA 1.0 has only one version of createNamedQuery which only accepts String and returns [Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) instance.

JPA 2.0 introduced another version of createNamedQuery in EntityManager class which accepts query string and typed class. It returns [TypedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) instance.

Reference : [EntityManager#createNamedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)